# andorid Picasso img from local file fit center crop

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

I have the fallowing code:

```
Picasso.with(mImageView.getContext()).load("file://" + filepath).fit().centerCrop()
                .into(mImageView);
```

When I load the file://filepath it doesn't appear full width. I tries to display the whole file and doesn't crop

When i load the same file from external url

```
Picasso.with(mImageView.getContext()).load(itemSrc).fit().centerCrop()
                .into(mImageView);
```

it work's just fine

why does picasso behave different when it loads a local file?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried without centerCrop .i.e.

```
Picasso.with(mImageView.getContext()).load("file://" + filepath).fit()
                .into(mImageView);
```